# How to change PageView scroll physics without rebuilding widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I want to change the `physics` from `PageScrollPhysics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` and back again without having to rebuild the `PageView`.

This is because I'm using it to render images that can be zoomed and the rebuild causes a blank image to appear before it loads again.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueNotifier Listener Builder` can solve your problem, it will rebuild only child widget if value change.

For more details - [ValueNotifierListenerBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html)